# Add a field from a different object on a VisualFoce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I am working on the Account VF page that has a custom controller (AccountPageController). On this page I would like to add a field (customField__c) from a different CustomObject__C.

What I have tried so far is on the AccountPageController I added the following code:

```
            public with sharing class AccountPageController {
            
                public List<Address__C> contactList {get;set;}
                    public void GetAddressInfo(){
                    contactList=[select CustomField1__c, CustomField2__c, ID1__c, ID2__c from CustomObject__c where ID1__c = :ID or ID2__c = :ID];
    
    }
}
```

And then on the VF page I have:

```
 <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="con">
         <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
         <apex:outputtext value="{!con.CustomField1__C}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageblock>
```

However, I don't receive an error but nothing shows up in that block, even if I add text. I am sure there is something wrong with my method. I'm really starting from scratch here so any help is appreciated.

---

Ok, so I have added that to my controller for account:

```
    //start
public List<Address__C> contactList {
   get {
        if (contactList == null) {
           contactList = [select Account1__c, Account2__c, CustomField__c
                           from CustomObject__c  
                            where ACCOUNT1__c = :acct.id or ACCOUNT2__c = :acct.id];
        }
        return contactList;
    } private set;
}

//end
```

However I don't get any errors, but I don't see those fields from the customobject__c on the  account page. Where on the controller page should that code go? Does it need to go into a certain area, does it need to be a constructor? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your getter so it actually fetches the values from the object when requested. Here, I'm using a lazy load pattern.

```
public List<Address__C> contactList {
   get {
        if (contactList == null) {
           contactList = [select CustomField1__c, CustomField2__c, ID1__c, ID2__c 
                            from CustomObject__c 
                            where ID1__c = :ID or ID2__c = :ID];
        }
        return contactList;
    } private set;
}
```

If the values of `this.ID` change; then be sure to null out the `contactList` so a new set of records is fetched when the VF page requests them

Comment: Thanks, so this is what I have in my controller for the account page: